# How to target body tag to close the side Navbar clicking any where on the screen using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to move the Navbar right: -500px (close the navbar) by clicking anywhere on the window. In Html, JS I can target body tag to do the same. How to do it in vue?
I have two functions for two (open and close) button. Still I want to add additional functionality to hide the Navbar by clicking anywhere on the screen.
My code

```
<div class="chatbot-whole-wrap">
    <PopUpMsg class="pop-up-chat" />
    <div class="chat-bot-wrapper">
        <input id="open" type="checkbox" />
        <img id="chat-btn" alt="chat-icon" src="@/assets/chat-bot-bee-icon.svg" @click="openWindow()" />
        <div id="sidebar">
            <img id="chat-close-btn" alt="chat-icon" src="@/assets/close-icon.svg" @click="closeWindow()" />
            <iframe class="chat-bot-iframe" src="https://hggsbnjsggxvbxjkksb/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are two methods I have used

```
methods: {
    openWindow() {
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.right = '0';
    },
    closeWindow() {
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.right = '-500px';
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most fluent in Vue.js, but could you not register an event handler on the body in a lifecycle method?

```js
function closeNavIfOpen () {
  console.log('do your thing')
}
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Click anywhere in the body!'
  },
  mounted () {
    window.document.body.addEventListener('click', closeNavIfOpen, false)
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.document.body.removeEventListener('click', closeNavIfOpen, false)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried but eslint is expecting short hand of mounted and destroyed both. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: also throwing an error handler.call is not a function

Comment: @SiddharthGope I just updated my answer to use the shorthand form I believe your linter is talking about. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: As for the error being thrown, I'm not seeing that when I run the snippet here in SO… Not sure what that's about, but as long as your handler is a function (in my case, the handler is `closeNavIfOpen` and it is a function) I believe this should work…